# Tornado: Are there Request Filters?

Tags: python, filter, tornado

I am looking at a Tornado app and wondering how to get it to perform my use case.  I need to intercept every request before dispatching to a URL handler and possibly return a redirect.  Is there a way to do this using Tornado?

I am wondering if Tornado has a concept of something like a servlet filter.  It looks like maybe the [input modifier](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.1/web.html#input) `decode_argument`does something like this?  It seems like it would be a bit of a hack to filter request using that method, but I haven't found anything else in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You have al least 3 options:

- Use `RequestHandler.prepare()` as [kamushin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195226/3219121).
- As said in [this tornado issue comment](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/49#issuecomment-99801):

  > You can hook up middleware, actually. HTTPServer request handlers are just callable objects (function, methods, or objects that implement `__call__`). You can write your own handler that passes on requests to your `Application`

(Example)

```
my_app = tornado.web.Application(...)

def middleware(request):
    # do whatever transformation you want here
    my_app(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(middleware)
    # ...
```

But notice that:

> Since Tornado request handling can be asynchronous, you can't modify the response in your middleware, but you can at least work with the request.

- Use a decorator. See [this exaemple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16886294/3219121) for details on how implementing it.
- Give a try to [tornado-middleware](https://github.com/Homeloc/tornado-middleware) or [tmiddleware](https://github.com/iamsk/tmiddleware). Be carefull since they're 3 years old and may not work. But you always can take a look at their code and learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RequestHandler.prepare()](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.prepare)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  Is this the best that can be done?  It seems like I need to override each request handler's prepare method.  Is there no global tornado request filter pipeline?

Comment: @DavidWilliams I think you can define a base class inherit RequestHandler